# flutter: convert CameraImage from camera plugin to base64 without store image in files (directly)

Tags: image, flutter, api, dart, camera

convert CameraImage from camera plugin to base64 without store image in files in flutter (directly)

anyone know how to do it in flutter
i have `CameraImage` from image stream but i can't convert it to base64

Comment: by saying "api" you mean that you want to make http POST request?

Comment: yes, but the problem not in the POST request the problem is how to convert CameraImge to base 64 from image stream

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/Base64Codec-class.html